# Two columns in twocolumn mode

Tags: two-column, multicol

I am trying to have two columns in the columns of a twocolumn mode (See the MWE. Please excuse that it is so long, it was the only way to illustrate what I mean). If the list extends the column it is continued on the next page, not on the right page side. How can I fix this? Many thanks!

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{multicols}{2}
Abkhaz\\
Adyghe\\
Afrikaans\\
Agul\\
Albanian\\
Altaic\\
ArmenianEastern\\
ArmenianGrabar\\
ArmenianWestern\\
Awar\\
Aymara\\
AzeriCyrillic\\
AzeriLatin\\
Bashkir\\
Basque\\
Belarusian\\
Bemba\\
Blackfoot\\
Breton\\
Bugotu\\
Bulgarian\\
Buryat\\
Catalan\\
Chamorro\\
Chechen\\
ChineseSimplified\\
ChineseTraditional\\
Chukcha\\
Chuvash\\
Corsican\\
CrimeanTatar\\
Croatian\\
Crow\\
Czech\\
Danish\\
Dargwa\\
Dungan\\
Dutch\\
DutchBelgian\\
Khanty\\
Kikuyu\\
Kirgiz\\
Kongo\\
Korean\\
Koryak\\
Kpelle\\
Kumyk\\
Kurdish\\
Lak\\
Lappish\\
Latin\\
Latvian\\
Lezgin\\
Lithuanian\\
Luba\\
Macedonian\\
Malagasy\\
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you not use `[twocolumn]` and just use `\begin{multicols}{2}...` most of the time and  `\begin{multicols}{4}...` where you want 4 columns?

Comment: If there is any way to still use twocolumn I would prefer that because the whole book is based on that. If it is not possible I guess I could switch back to onecolumn and then use your approach

Comment: Sorry, but `multicol` doesn't fully support `twocolumn` mode (there's warning about that). I think the best way is to go with the solution of @DavidCarlisle.

Comment: If your 4-column data is always an exampleset like this, you may want to consider using a breakable `tabular` environment (like `longtable`, `xtab`, `supertabular` or `ltablex`). It is not as convenient, but may save you the trouble of switching between 2 and 4 column modes.

Comment: Well if I use a breakable tabular environment i guess i need to put in the separators manually? This would be kind of annoying since the tabular should go down, not from left to right

Comment: @Kathiieee Yes, that is the case in this alternative. (If you want someone to be notified of your comment use the @<name> command as I did here - the owner of the question will always receive notifications).

Comment: @masu Alright, thank you :) Well in that case I will leave it in the original two column mode (where it needs much space) than putting separators manually in a list of about 300 Languages.

Comment: @Kathiieee this problem raised a question for me. What about generating a warning if the columnbreak is "mispositioned"? Would that help? I've just submitted it to the site [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138858/specify-warning-based-on-distance-from-the-bottom).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: MWE]

As a MWE is better than a thousand words, here you can how to switch from one to two columns without `multicol` package (without any trick that mean a new page) as well as having `multicols` inside a column (that must fit well within the parent column, or you will obtain amusing results ...).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\twocolumn[
\section{One column}
{\lipsum*[2]}
\bigskip]

\section{Two columns}

A little text that show the width of one normal column.

\section{Mini columns}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}

\section{Again two columns}
\lipsum[5]

\section{Again mini columns}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}

\onecolumn

\lipsum[1-3]

\twocolumn[\section{Return to the two columns}
{\lipsum*[2]}
\bigskip]

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```