# Throw warning based on distance from the bottom

Tags: positioning, warnings

Is there a way to specify a warning in `LaTeX` which is thrown if and only if a specified text is not at the bottom (or near the bottom) of the page?

Use-case: manual column-breaking is needed due to some package shortcoming, the warning is there to warn the user if the column break has moved upwards or downwards on the page.

related: [Two columns in twocolumn mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138776/two-columns-in-twocolumn-mode?noredirect=1#comment312976_138776)

Comment: look at `needspace` package (although it isn't infallible)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think there won't be an infallible solution for this, so thanks anyway.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wanna make your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B my comment is same as wills answer here, I'll  vote duplicate

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Followwed your lead.