# Onecolumn command in twocolumn article

Tags: macros, environments, documentclass-writing

I'm making a class (.cls) for CVs, and I'm loading the `[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}` class. However, I would like a sort of "heading" section which should only have one column. It's going to look something like this:
[image]

I want to define a new environment `fullwidth` to do this. I have tried:

```
\newenvironment{fullwidth}[1]{%
  \onecolumn}{\twocolumn}

\RequirePackage{multicol}
\newenvironment{fullwidth}[1]{%
  \begin{multicols}{1}{\endmulticols}
```

but none of these works. When using `onecolumn` anything put in the environment does not show up, and `multicols` just switch to two columns because the multicol package "thinks it's a bad idea to have one column here". Any tips?

The document should look something like (where `myclass` is the document class I'm writing):

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{fullwidth}
    A lot of text and the header, printed by the command \makecvtitle .
\end{fullwidth}

Rest of CV in twocolumn
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not simply go for `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{multicol}

\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text using the \lipsum command

\begin{document}
A lot of text and the header, printed by the command %\makecvtitle .

\begin{multicols}{2}
Rest of CV in twocolumn \lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}`?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/138861/11604

Comment: You probably want \twocolumn[...] which can be called while in twocolumn.  Note that both \onecolumn and \twocolumn start new pages.  BTW, you might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477188/removing-the-space-in-the-page-before-appendix/477197?r=SearchResults&s=3|0.0000#477197 interesting.